# Can't get an updated array from the class function in js

Tags: javascript, class, oop

```
class Store {
  constructor(items) {
    this._items = items;
  }
  getItems() {
    const storages = [this._items];
    return storages;
  }
  addItem(item) {
    storages = [...this._items, ...item];
    return storages;
  }
}

const storage = new Storage([
  'cucumber',
  'tomato',
  'banana',
  'egg',
]);

const items = storage.getItems();
console.table(items); 

storage.addItem.bind('garlic');
console.table(storage.items);
```

Instead of getting an updated array from  storage.addItem.bind('garlic'), i keep getting 'undefined'. function of addItem is to add item to the array. Can't implement it in a class.

why i am getting undefined from bind? what do i need to do to fix the grogramm?

Comment: Where does that `.bind` come from? It seems you just want to directly invoke `storage.addItem('garlic');`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try it

```
class Store {
  constructor(items) {
    this._items = items;
  }
  getItems() {
    return this._items;
  }
  addItem(item) {
    this._items = [...this._items, item]; // Fix
    return this._items;
  }
}

const storage = new Store([ // Fix
  'cucumber',
  'tomato',
  'banana',
  'egg',
]);

let items = storage.getItems(); // Fix
console.table(items); 

storage.addItem('garlic'); // Fix
items = storage.getItems(); // Get new items because created new array after add item
console.table(items);
```

or try it if you don`t need create new array after adding item

```
class Store {
  constructor(items) {
    this._items = items;
  }
  getItems() {
    return this._items;
  }
  addItem(item) {
    this._items.push(item); // Fix
    return this._items;
  }
}

const storage = new Store([ // Fix
  'cucumber',
  'tomato',
  'banana',
  'egg',
]);

let items = storage.getItems(); // Fix
console.table(items); 

storage.addItem('garlic'); // Fix
console.table(items);
```

bind return new function with set context. 
but in your case it is not necessary

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you have bind confused with what you are trying to accomplish.  The purpose of the `bind` method is to give your function a permanent `this` at calltime.  Don't worry too much about it. 
Also it seems like you are passing an array when calling your new Class so you don't need to add another one in your getItems method. This should work:

```js
class Store {
  constructor(items) {
    this._items = items;
  }
  getItems() {
    return this._items
  }
  addItem(item) {
    this._items.push(item)
    return item;
  }
}

const storage = new Storage([
  'cucumber',
  'tomato',
  'banana',
  'egg',
]);

const items = storage.getItems();
console.log(items); 

const itemAdded = storage.addItem('garlic');
console.log(itemAdded);
```

Hope this helps!